# Flextable R activate page break for a table in Word

Tags: r, page-break, flextable, officer

I am using the officer and flextable packages to write reports in word.

When I use the body_add_flextable() function, the tables always start on a new page because the

"do not separate from the next paragraph" is activated in Word paragraph settings.

How can I deactivate this in the flextable settings.

```
doc <- read_docx("template.docx")

tab<-airquality

doc <- body_add_table(doc,tab)

tab<-flextable(tab)

doc <- body_add_flextable(doc,tab)

print(doc, target = "test_template.docx")
```

The body_add_table() function works without the break the body_add_flextable() not.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zB5Xx.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ID1P.png]

Thank you

Zies

Comment: I think it is fixed since version 0.8. Do you have the latest cran version?

Comment: Yes I am using 0.8.2.

Comment: can you share a reproducible example then?

Comment: Thank you, it's a bug, we will try to fix it soon

Comment: it should be fixed now in the github version